# how to install pdo_dblib

Tags: 12.04, installation

I want to install `pdo_dblib` for my application but don't know how to do that and what things I need. How can I install `pdo_dblib` in my ubuntu 12.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sybase
```

If you want to know more check its [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-dblib.php)

Comment: does this means that it's presnt in ubuntu repository with the name `php5-sybase` ? and what about the thing to add line `extension=xx` in `php.ini`?

Comment: yes its presented in Ubuntu repos.

Comment: and do I need to add the line `extension=pdo_sybase.so` in `php.ini`?

Comment: No need of that